# select CSS only if first sibling is something

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I select an IMG only if the first sibling is a DIV?

```
<img src="something"></img>
<div>...</div>
```

This is not a dup as marked, I don't want to select the following sibling as the dup addresses, but the element that the following one is relative to, in this case the IMG.